# Filter power pivot using selections from another pivot table

Tags: excel, vba, powerpivot

I created a power pivot (KPI-1) with three working slicers. Instead of slicers, I'd prefer to filter KPI-1 using a selection from another power pivot (Pharmacies) within the same workbook.

I created a second power pivot (KPI-2) without slicers on a new sheet in the same workbook, and then created slicer connections to the first power pivot (KPI-1). I can successfully use the slicers from KPI-1 to filter KPI-2.

Is there any way to directly filter a power pivot based on a selection from another power pivot table, OR is there a way to pass the selection from power pivot Pharmacies to KPI-1's slicers, which will then filter my slicerless KPI-2? I could then just hide KPI-1.

Comment: Lisa, can you please share a bit of data structure - is the slicer filtering the same column?

Comment: My slicers are disconnected slicers, but I created relationships between the slicers and the Power Pivot data.

Comment: The "Pharmacies" Power Pivot contains the same data as my two slicers. I'd like the user to be able to select a pharmacy-facility intersection from the "Pharmacies" Power Pivot and pass the pharmacy and facility values (my 2 slicers) to my KPI Power Pivot.

Comment: Sample workbook with sample data? :)

Answer (score 1):

- Click into pivot table `KPI-1` and press `Insert -> Slicer`
- Right click the slicer and select `Report Connections...`
- Check the `KPI-2` pivot table

All filters set in pivot table `KPI-1` will be transferred to the Slicer and all connected pivot tables.

This only works, if the two pivot tables have the same data source!